# How to find out the end of an jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, promise

Can I find out the end of an event with

```
$._data(this, "events")
```

What I basically want to do is disable buttons so double form submits and double action can't be made. When it's a normal submit button I do the followings:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("button[js-hide=1]").click(function() {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).html("<img src=\"loading5.gif\" />");
        })
    })
</script>
```

This works just fine, disables button, and loads a gif until the pase is loaded again.

Now I want the exact same process for simple jQuery buttons. It can be a simple AJAX request or a button that copies one field of text to another. The thing is the button must be disabled until the action is done. I know I could just do the disable / enable thing at the start and the end of a function , but that's not a solution. Cause I want this in a framework.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("button[js-hide=0]").click(function() {
            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
            $(this).html("<img src=\"loading5.gif\" />");
            console.log( $._data(this, "events"))';
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Let's not bicker about the form; the point Barta Tamás is making is perfectly clear. I've editted the question to reflect the actual JS.

Comment: @andyb Better now? Tjeez...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a look at jQuery [promises](http://api.jquery.com/promise/), specifically `done()` (and/or `then()`)

Comment: Edited your answer as I mis-clicked -1 instead of +1 and could not re-vote until the answer was edited :-)

Comment: Sorry, yes it was me. I never downvote intentionally without leaving an explanation!